# How to hide a textfield in main report based on the value returned by subreport in jasper ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a main report and a subreport and i want to hide a textfield based on the value returned by the subreport.

How to achieve this in jasper ireport?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass value returned from subreport to main report.
If you use Jaspersoft Studio find `Subreport Return Values` in subreport properties :

[image: parameters]

So in this table you can set from which `value` in subreport to which in main report you will pass you values. Then you can access subreport value from main report variable.